# PHP Check Array with Post

Tags: php, arrays, post

How can a PHP script check if a value is in an array?
I want it to check if a password input is equal to those in an array.

e.g. if $input == "pass1" or "pass2" or "pass3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function for checking if a variable is in an array is [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Like this:

```
if (in_array($input, array("pass1", "pass2", "pass3")) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

from php manual:

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict =
>   FALSE ] ) Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless
>   strict is set.

```
if(in_array($input, $somearray)){ .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much copying what Marc B stated in his comment, the example code is

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

And in this example the second if would fail because "mac" is not contained in the array.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple methods. `in_array` is one, and `foreach` is another. I don't know which is faster, but here's how you'd do it with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
 if ($a == "correct password") {
  //do something
 }
}
```

Comment: Bet on `in_array`. Not sure why you would use `foreach` here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way,

```
if(count(array_intersect(array($input), array("pass1", "pass2", "pass3"))) > 0){
     //do stuff
}
```